# Increment Row Number on Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am working on a query for SQL Server 2005 that needs to return data with two 'index' fields. The first index 't_index' should increment every time the 'shade' column changes, whilst the second index increments within the partition of the values in the 'shade' column:

```
t_index s_index shade
1       1       A
1       2       A
1       3       A
1       4       A
1       5       A
2       1       B
2       2       B
2       3       B
2       4       B
2       5       B
```

To get the s_index column I am using the following:

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [shade] ORDER BY [shade]) as s_index
```

My question is how to get the first index to only increment when the value in the 'shade' column changes?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

That can be accomplished with the `DENSE_RANK()` function:

```
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(Order By [shade]) as t_index
```

Answer (score 73):

You can try to use `DENSE_RANK()` for that:

```
SELECT
    shade,
    s_index = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [shade] ORDER BY [shade]),
    t_index = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [shade])
FROM dbo.YourTableNameHEre
```

Gives output:

```
shade  s_index  t_index
  A      1        1
  A      2        1
  A      3        1
  A      4        1
  A      5        1
  B      1        2
  B      2        2
  B      3        2
  B      4        2
  B      5        2
```

Comment: This will not work if shade reverts to a previous value.

Comment: And heteregeneous result set.. how to?

Comment: For the case where shade reverts to a previous value (also linked) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570598/increment-row-number-on-group-with-repeated-groups