# Increment row number on group with repeated groups

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, dense-rank

I am working on a query for PLSQL (Oracle 12), in which I need to increment the row number of a dataset for each group.

My problem is similar to this question  ([Increment Row Number on Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116275/increment-row-number-on-group)). However, I have a slightly different scenario. I have the same *shade* repeated over the data, and I want to keep the original order when grouping.

For the data below

```
Level | Shade
-------------
1     | A
2     | A
3     | A
4     | B
5     | B
6     | B
7     | A
8     | A
9     | A
```

I want to get the following result

```
Group | Shade | Amount
----------------------
1     | A     | 3
2     | B     | 3
3     | A     | 3
```

If I use the DENSE_RANK function ordering by *Shade*, I am not able to keep the original order, and this is what I get:

```
Group | Shade | Amount
----------------------
1     | A     | 6
2     | B     | 3
```

How could I keep the original group pattern when grouping?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the difference of row numbers to define the groups:

```
select Shade, count(*) as amount
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by level) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by shade order by level) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t
group by Shade, (seqnum - seqnum_s);
```

It is a little hard to explain why this works.  If you look at the results of the subquery, it becomes obvious why the difference between the two `row_number()` values identify sequential groups.