# Incorrect row numbering on group

Tags: mysql

and thanks for helping me learn mysql.

I'm trying to dynamically-generate row numbers that only increment when there is a new record in a group (for a given column). My code sort of works - it changes when it should, but the values are all wrong.

I have a table called `fruits` with only one column (`varchar`) called `preference`. It has nine (9) records in this order:

```
Apples
Pears
Apples
Oranges
Bananas
Pears
Oranges
Apples
Bananas
```

Its the same challenge (the `t-index`) posed in [Increment Row Number on Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116275/increment-row-number-on-group) but that solution used (I think) a new `mysql` `Window` function that is only available (I think) in `mysql` `v8`, which isn't supported by my web host (as `CPanel` doesn't yet support).

Here is my code...

```
SET @row_num=1,@currFruit='';

SELECT @row_num=CASE WHEN fruit.preference=@currFruit 
                    THEN @row_num 
                    ELSE @row_num:=@row_num+1 END AS 'RowNum', 
    preference, @currFruit:=fruit.preference    
FROM fruit
ORDER BY fruit.preference;
```

The results show the dynamically-generated row numbers changing when it should, but the initial value is wrong, it shouldn't reset each group, they don't keep incrementing (apples should be 1, 2, 3), (bananas should be 1, 2), (Oranges 1,2), (Pears 1,2)

Here is the **incorrect output**....

```
@RowNum  preference         @currFruit:=fruit.preference
0        Apples             Apples
1        Apples             Apples
1        Apples             Apples
0        Bananas            Bananas
1        Bananas            Bananas
0        Oranges            Oranges
1        Oranges            Oranges
0        Pears              Pears
1        Pears              Pears
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=` in `@row_num = CASE ...` is comparing `@row_num` to the result of the `CASE` expression, which returns `1` for true and `0` for false. You should be assigning with `:=` there.

You also have the consequences of the `CASE` wrong. When it's the same as `@currFruit` you should add 1, otherwise you should set it back to 1.

```
SELECT @row_num := CASE WHEN fruit.preference=@currFruit 
                    THEN @row_num + 1
                    ELSE 1 END AS 'RowNum', 
    preference, @currFruit:=fruit.preference    
FROM fruit
ORDER BY fruit.preference
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oYhy9vcu2WRjZAKeha2p93/0)

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I see what you mean about the missing assignment operator. But the code doesn't give the intended solution - RowNum is supposed to remain unchanged from the previous record when fruit.preference=@currFruit, so I amended your code (see below) but for some reason the first RowNum is 2 (it should be 1).

Comment: Your question says the number is supposed to increment: "apples should be 1, 2, 3"

Comment: Sorry Barmar - my mistake. Your code almost works (after dropping the +1) and instead putting it as 'ELSE @row_num+1', but still has an incorrect RowNum of "2" for the first record (which should be "1").

Comment: If you want the first rownum to be 1, then initialize it as `@row_num := 0`.